# How to update version when my app was uploaded on to CH Play

Tags: flutter, google-play-services, auto-update

I have an app mobile wroted by flutter already uploaded on to CH Play (version 1). After that, i update some feature on my app on my local (not yet upload on CH play) how to notice every one that use my app update version.

Comment: What is CH play is it similar to play store.

Comment: Yeah, Rahul i'm looking for this

Comment: Best approach is use google Analytics. For flutter you can use Google analytics with  Firebase : https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup, https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics, Firebase for Android : https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/android-quickstart-google-analytics-firebase-google-tag-manager/,

Comment: What is this CH Play, please tell me. I have never heard this term.